# Cayenne stripes inside fried chicken strips how is it made?

Tags: chicken, cheese

[image]We've all been to KFC and had those spicy chicken strips.. and also fried chicken legs wings etc.. my questions is how does the cayenne powder or sauce get inside the chicken strips  ? By needle ? Everytime u take a bit u find red stripes inside.

Comment: I'd like to remind everybody that we have a policy against answering in comments. I'm deleting the existing ones, please if you have an idea, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Good luck pinning them down on that trade secret! ;-) KFC claims their chicken strips are in fact strips of whole chicken, not ground and formed meat. If there are stripes inside, they are almost certainly injected into the meat. If you wanted to make them at home, you can buy meat injectors pretty cheaply. Remember, it's not just cayenne in there– there are other spices like smoked paprika, black pepper, and other things to buffer the spice so you don't just burn your face off without a whole lot of flavor. I'm sure you could fry up a delicious approximation of the real thing at home.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you can do is take a thin blade and cut a small pocket and then you can insert anything.